# accessing function variables in a constructor

Tags: javascript, oop, scope

I have a constructor function (or class if you will) and part of my code is running an interval. I am trying to clear the interval but the `countDown`  variable is not accessible in the `countDown` function.

**Please note:** Both the `countDown` and the `startTimer` functions are inside a constructor function.

Here is the code:

```
this.startTimer = function() {
    if (!isOn) {
        timeFormatter();
        if (timeArray[0] === "0") {
            return error(" You need to work longer than that! ")
        }
        isOn = true;
 var startCountDown = setInterval(this.countDown.bind(this),1000);
    }
}

this.countDown = function() {
    //Once timer ends, stop function.
    if (timeArray[0] === 0
     && timeArray[2] === 0
     && timeArray[3] === 1) {
        element.innerHTML = 0;
        counter = 0;
        isOn = false;
        clearInterval(startCountDown) //I get error here. countDown is not accessible.
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you access countDown within the startTimer function, it's only available within this scope. If you want the var to be globally accessible, define it globally (outside the function scopes).

Comment: Adding to @Lupinity's comment: declare it as a member of your class.  Also, don't call it countDown, it will conflict with the `countDown` function

Comment: If I define it outside the function then it will fire earlier, and I need it to fire within the start timer function. I want to avoid using undelcared global variables.

Comment: @Tibrogargan can you explain what you mean?

Comment: @theNeighbourhoodGhost `countDown` is a property of `this`.  Even if you declare a separate variable in either the global scope or as a member of this you will get a name conflict.  You can't have two identifiers with the same name - one will hide the other.  You especially cannot have two properties with the same name.  You can't access the `var countDown` declared inside the startTimer function because the scope of that declaration is local.  You similarly couldn't access it even if it was global because `this.countDown` would hide it

Comment: @Tibrogargan ok I changed that part, but how can I declare it so it's within the constructor function but doesn't execute until I run startTimer?

Comment: @theNeighbourhoodGhost update the code in your question please

Comment: Do **not** store the return value of setInterval in a variable declared inside a function.  That declaration will **never** be visible outside the function.  Just declare the variable at a global scope and leave it undefined.

Comment: @Tibrogargan I got it, declared it as part of the class and it worked. thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You could simply store the **countdown** in your function object then bind it to **this** instead in this

```
this.countdown = setInterval()
```

Then bind the functions to **this**.

```
this.startTimer = function(){
    if(!isOn){
    timeFormatter();
        if(timeArray[0] === "0"){
            return error(" You need to work longer than that! ")
        }
    isOn = true;    
    this.countDown = setInterval(this.countDown.bind(this),1000);
    }
}.bind(this); // this

this.countDown = function () {

  //Once timer ends, stop function.
  if (timeArray[0] === 0 && timeArray[2] === 0 && timeArray[3] === 1) {
    element.innerHTML = 0;
    counter = 0;
    isOn = false;
    clearInterval(this.countdown);
    return null;

  }
}.bind(this); // and this one
```

OR store the variable on a higher level

```
var countDown; // this

this.startTimer = function(){
    if(!isOn){
    timeFormatter();
        if(timeArray[0] === "0"){
            return error(" You need to work longer than that! ")
        }
    isOn = true;    
    countDown = setInterval(this.countDown.bind(this),1000);
    }
}

this.countDown = function () {

  //Once timer ends, stop function.
  if (timeArray[0] === 0 && timeArray[2] === 0 && timeArray[3] === 1) {
    element.innerHTML = 0;
    counter = 0;
    isOn = false;
    clearInterval(countDown) //I get error here. countDown is not accessible.
    return null;

  }
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Did you actually test this code?  Both versions will fail